# Как реализована функция remove в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

может кто знает как именно реализована функция `remove`, то есть с помощью каких методов работает данная функция в Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/dbf8613a2ef189592d55054c3939430f5a5977ae/Objects/listobject.c#L2649

```c
static PyObject *
list_remove(PyListObject *self, PyObject *value)
/*[clinic end generated code: output=f087e1951a5e30d1 input=2dc2ba5bb2fb1f82]*/
{
    Py_ssize_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < Py_SIZE(self); i++) {
        PyObject *obj = self->ob_item[i];
        Py_INCREF(obj);
        int cmp = PyObject_RichCompareBool(obj, value, Py_EQ);
        Py_DECREF(obj);
        if (cmp > 0) {
            if (list_ass_slice(self, i, i+1,
                               (PyObject *)NULL) == 0)
                Py_RETURN_NONE;
            return NULL;
        }
        else if (cmp < 0)
            return NULL;
    }
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "list.remove(x): x not in list");
    return NULL;
}
```

В двух словах - проматывает список до нужного объекта, дальше делает срез списка