# Выделается ли новая память при использовании срезов в цикле в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Выделается ли новая память при использовании срезов в цикле в Python?

Comment: Если речь про списки, то для каждого нового среза списка выделяется память. Сами элементы нового списка (среза) остаются ссылками на элементы старого списка.

Comment: @insolor Если "элементы нового списка (среза) остаются ссылками" - то если я поменяю значение в срезе, оно должно поменяться и в оригинале

Comment: @Виктор не совсем правильно выразился, ссылками на значения в списке. Если значение мутабельное (например, другой список), то при его модификации (например, добавлении элементов в подсписок), изменения будут отображаться и в исходном списке, и в списке-результате среза.

Comment: @insolor добавлял, удалял, менял - не изменяется в другом списке

Comment: @Виктор, вот вам пример кода с демонстрацией этого поведения: https://pastebin.com/W0vSRTDm

Comment: @insolor не надо путать массив, с аналогом двумерного массива. a = ['a','b','c','d']
b = a[::-1]
a[0] = 'f'
print(a,b)

Comment: @Виктор я ничего не путаю. Подсписок - это пример мутабельного элемента основного списка. Вместо него можно использовать объект какого-нибудь своего класса, при изменении атрибута это изменение будет видно и в исходном списке, и в срезе, т.к. в обоих списках хранится ссылка на один и тот же объект.

Comment: @Виктор `a = ['a','b','c','d'] b = a[::-1] a[0] = 'f' print(a,b)` - 1 - строки иммутабельны, 2 - вы не мутируете значение (предположим, что вместо строк были бы мутабельные объекты), а заменяете на другое значение. 3 - не делайте мне мозг. Прочитайте внимательно мой уточняющий комментарий.

Comment: ответ на вопрос явно зависит от реализации интерпретатора. то есть, дать на него объективный ответ будет, вероятно, затруднительно.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin в принципе, по умолчанию можно считать, что имеется в виду реализация CPython, и просто привести фрагмент исходников, как в ответе на прошлый вопрос участника https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1472565/1365

Comment: "А почему вы спрашиваете?" Даже если память выделяется, вопрос в том, что вы потом делаете с этим срезом. Если просто помещаете в какую-то переменную на время, то с каждым новым циклом эта переменная забывается, потом это место почистит сборщик мусора (когда-нибудь). Так почему вы задаёте этот вопрос? Может есть какой-то конкретный код и какая-то конкретная проблема?